# Disabling DHCP/bridging WAN on OpenWRT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp, openwrt

I have an LTE Router (192.168.1.2) and an OpenWRT router (192.168.1.1) that I want to be the single entity providing WiFi, all with the 255.255.255.0 subnet mask. The LTE Router is connected via Ethernet to the OpenWRT device on its "internet" port (which I believe to be the WAN port displayed in LuCI).

I'd like to completely deactivate WiFi on the LTE router and use the full 802.11ax capabilities of my OpenWRT router. This configuration, however, fails with what I believe to be conflicting addresses provided by the two DHCP servers. For instance, once I connect the OpenWRT router to the LTE one, it's assigned address becomes 192.168.1.132, and I can't access LuCI neither on the old, nor on that new IP address. The LTE router claims that the DHCP server is at 192.168.1.2 (correct) -- if I disable DHCP on the LTE router, no traffic at all is possible, and I must do a cold reset in order to get it back in working condition. (It's an Alcatel LinkHub with highly limited settings.)

There should be a way to configure the WAN input (i.e., the "internet" port) of the OpenWRT router in a way that all WiFi networks provided by this router connect to this port. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the LAN settings of OpenWRT and disable the DHCP server for the LAN interface. Then connect any of its LAN interfaces to the LAN interface of the LTE router, leaving WAN of the OpenWRT unconnected. OpenWRT device will act as a switch and access point.

If you are using LuCi (OpenWRT web interface), you go to Network->Interfaces->Edit on LAN interface and on the bottom of the page you **check** the box "Ignore this interface". Or, if you prefer editing config files, that's `/etc/config/dhcp`, add `option ignore '1'` to your LAN section. DHCP on the LTE router will provide IP address and other configuration (gateway, DNS servers) to all wired and wireless clients connected to OpenWRT's LAN (which is a bridge that contains your wireless interfaces, two of them I believe, and wired LAN ports).

For OpenWRT to have an Internet connection itself, you might want to set up static IP on the LAN interface and add specify a LTE address as a gateway. Simply put the local address of LTE (192.168.1.2) into the "gateway" field in the WebUI LAN interface setup (the same page where you also disable its own DHCP).

Comment: So what you're suggesting is to use the OpenWRT router as switch, correct? And the DCHP server on the LTE router would provide any device connected to the OpenWRT router with an IP address? Regarding your last suggestion with setting up an LTE router address as gateway, I'm too much of a network rookie to understand that. Could you explain what you mean, please?

Comment: OpenWRT will act as a switch and access point. DHCP on the LTE router will provide IP address and other configuration (gateway, DNS servers) to all wired and wireless clients connected to OpenWRT's LAN (which is a bridge that contains your wireless interfaces, two of them I believe, and wired LAN ports). To set up a gateway on OpenWRT, simply put local address of LTE (`192.168.1.2`) into the "gateway" field in the WebUI LAN interface setup (the same page where you also disable its own DHCP).

Comment: Hi @nikita, thanks for your support! This seems to be working. I still seem to be having trouble with some WiFi devices, but these might very well be problems with the WiFi standard. For instance, I do believe that my kids' tablet won't connect since it doesn't support 802.11ax -- ist that a possibility?

Comment: Yes. Also it could be that you enabled only [TKIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_Key_Integrity_Protocol) security (which is broken and should not be used, by the way) which is banned in some new devices, or vice versa, you enabled only [CCMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCMP_(cryptography)) (modern and secure) and some ancient devices don't know how to use that. Or you configured wireless channel that isn't reachable by some devices (due to regional settings or technical limitations). WiFi is set of evolving standards and as such can have various compatibility issues.

Comment: Well, I do have configure WPA2-PSK/WPA3-SAE on both the 802.11bgn as well as the 802.11acax channels. Changing the country code from "driver default" to my country code didn't do the trick, either.